# Modificando um JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Eu gostaria de fazer duas coisa:

**1º:** adicionar um label, ou qualquer coisa, que me permita colocar um "texto" abaixo das cores. Exemplo na ilustração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2º:** Fazer com que o ponteiro/indicador do `slider`, vá para a cor de acordo com o um determinado número digitado no campo (no método abaixo está mais claro de entender)

```
package pacote01;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Slider extends JFrame {

    public static final Color[] COLORS = {Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue};
    private static final int COMPRIMENTO = 30;
    private static final int ALTURA = 10;

    private JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);
    public JTextField campo = new JTextField();

    private double valor;

    public Slider() {
        setSize(525, 300);
        add(montaSlider());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent montaSlider() {
        JPanel jpSlider = new JPanel();

        jpSlider.add(campo);
        campo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

        campo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()//Caixa consulta é o campo que é digitado o código.
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                            definePonteiro();
                        } else {

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        int majorSpacing = slider.getMaximum() / (COLORS.length - 1);
        Dictionary<Integer, JLabel> dictionary = new Hashtable<>();
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(majorSpacing);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {
            ImageIcon icon = createColorIcon(COLORS[i]);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            int key = i * majorSpacing;
            dictionary.put(key, label);
        }
        slider.setLabelTable(dictionary);
        jpSlider.add(slider, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return jpSlider;
    }

    private ImageIcon createColorIcon(Color color) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(COMPRIMENTO, ALTURA, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, COMPRIMENTO, ALTURA);
        g.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Slider s = new Slider();
            }
        });
    }

    public void definePonteiro() {
        valor = Double.valueOf(campo.getText());
        if (valor <= 11.5) {
            //seta o ponteiro na 1ª cor
            System.out.println("1ª");
        } else if (valor <= 20) {
            //seta o ponteiro na 2ª cor
            System.out.println("2ª");
        } else if (valor <= 30) {
            //seta o ponteiro na 3 cor
            System.out.println("3ª");
        } else if (valor <= 40) {
            //seta o ponteiro na 4ª cor
            System.out.println("4ª");
        } else if (valor <= 50) {
            //seta o ponteiro na 5ª cor
            System.out.println("5ª");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1º: adicionar um label, ou qualquer coisa, que me permita colocar um "texto" abaixo das cores.

Ao invés de posicionar abaixo, fiz uma forma alternativa e que altera o minimo possível seu código, posicionando os valores internamente nos labels coloridos.

Para isso, primeiro precisaria criar uma array de tamanho idêntico ao do array `COLORS`, colocando os valores nele:

```
public static final Color[] COLORS = {Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue};
//5 cores, 5 valores
public static final String[] valuesColor = {"10", "20","30","40","50"};
```

depois, aproveitando o laço que você utiliza para preencher as cores, adicione estes valores como texto nos labels, alinhando horizontalmente no centro em seguida:

```
for (int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {
    ImageIcon icon = createColorIcon(COLORS[i]);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    //aqui você vai adicionar o valor
    //correspondente a cor de mesmo indice
    label.setText(valuesColor[i]);
    label.setForeground(Color.white);//altere a cor dos números como quiser aqui
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);//centraliza o texto
    int key = i * majorSpacing;
    dictionary.put(key, label);
}
```

Com essas alterações, os valores serão exibidos dentro dos labels coloridos.

> 2º: Fazer com que o ponteiro/indicador do slider, vá para a cor de acordo com o um determinado número digitado no campo

Basta utilizar a boa e velha matemática :)

Seu slider é iniciado com 100 sendo seu valor máximo e 0 sendo seu valor minimo, como são 5 cores, logo cada *tick* do slider é igual a `100/5`, ou seja, o espaço entre cada "tracinho" é 25. Sabendo desta informação, basta posicionar o *knob* conforme o label abaixo dele:

```
public void definePonteiro() {

    valor = Double.valueOf(campo.getText());
    //variavel que armazenará a posicao do knob
    int sliderPos = 0;

    if (valor <= 11.5) {          
        sliderPos = 0;
    } else if (valor <= 20) {
        sliderPos = 25;
    } else if (valor <= 30) {
        sliderPos = 50;
    } else if (valor <= 40) {
        sliderPos = 75;
    } else if (valor <= 50) {
        sliderPos = 100;
    }
    slider.setValue(sliderPos);
}
```

Veja o resultado das duas mudanças em funcionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, tu é fera !

Comment: uma dúvida, eu agora tentei fazer o processamento (capturar o texto) em outra classe, e tentei passar como parâmetro para a classe Slider, porém não deu certo. Eu fiz slider = new Slider(valorDaVarialvel); depois do calculo.

Comment: @Java o certo não seria passar para o método `definePonteiro()`? A lógica é a mesma da atual, só que ao inves de capturar do campo de texto, você passa o valor recebido para os ifs.

Comment: então, é a mesma lógica, usando o system.out eu confirmei que o valor tem, mais não esta funcionando, sera que o valor esta sendo perdido quando eu passo para o definePonteiro() na outra classe?

Comment: @Java testando aqui, deu certo. Testa ai tambem: https://pastebin.com/4rUmTxSE

Comment: será que é porque eu estou usando float ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8Pi0FSU4 olha ai como eu fiz, fazendo favor.

Comment: @Java nesse código você não chama o método `definePonteiro()` nunca. Ai nada vai acontecer mesmo. E JSlider só recebe int, você precisa fazer cast para int senão seu código nem vai compilar.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8Pi0FSU4 converti o valor, e chamei o método no construtor, talvez a chamada esteja errada ?

Comment: @Java não problema algum nesse código, mudei o imc para 50 e o slider iniciou na ultima posicao.

Comment: esse ultimo que eu postei ? Aqui não foi não :(

Comment: @Java complicado, testei aqui e mudou normalmente. Tente criar um novo projeto, copiando as classes para ele, pode ser o cache da IDE.

Comment: eu não consegui, mais vou refazer aqui para ver se encontro o erro.

Comment: acredito que sei o porque do erro, porém não sei o que poderia ser feito, se isso for realmente a causa. Eu espalhei uns system.out e percebi que deixando a chamada do método no construtor, ele esta executado so de adicionar o componente na tela, porém ta td 0. depois quando digita o valor, e faz processamento de td correto, mais não seta o ponteiro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59505/discussion-between-diegofm-and-java).