# Controlar velocidade de animação utilizando o componente JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Bom galera, estou desenvolvendo um projetinho que visa simular o ambiente controlado de trilhos de trem, onde tenho 3 trens circulando em sentido horário, onde os três passam pelo mesmo local em determinados trechos. Estou com dificuldade em implementar a velocidade dos trens dinamicamente utilizando o componente `JSlider`. Consegui criar os 3 componentes, porém ainda não consegui associá-los aos meus trens.

Segue o código:

```
public class Trens {

private static final double QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO = 20.0;

public static void preparar() {
    JFrame t = new JFrame();
    t.setLayout(null);
    t.setSize(1200, 900);
    t.setTitle("Semáforo");
    t.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    t.setResizable(false);
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Trilho t1 = new Trilho(300, 100, 300, 170);
    Trilho t2 = new Trilho(600, 100, 300, 170);
    Trilho t3 = new Trilho(450, 270, 300, 170);
    Jslider slider = new Jslider(30, 150, 300, 170);
    Jslider slider2 = new Jslider(900, 150, 300, 170);
    Jslider slider3 = new Jslider(150, 330, 300, 170);

    Trem a = new Trem(t1, Color.BLUE, 350, 100, 100.0);
    Trem b = new Trem(t2, Color.GREEN, 650, 100, 100.0);
    Trem c = new Trem(t3, Color.RED, 450, 335, 100.0);
    t.add(a);
    t.add(b);
    t.add(c);
    t.add(t1);
    t.add(t2);
    t.add(t3);
    t.add(slider);
    t.add(slider2);
    t.add(slider3);
    Runnable moverTudo = () -> {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            a.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
            b.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
            c.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
        });
    };
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(moverTudo, 0, (int) (1000 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    t.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(Trens::preparar);
}

public static class Trilho extends JComponent {
    public Trilho(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }
}

public static class Trem extends JComponent {
    private Color cor;
    private Trilho trilho;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private double velocidade; // pixels por segundo
    private double restante; // Frações de pixels que faltou andar.

    public Trem(Trilho trilho, Color cor, int x, int y, double velocidade) {
        this.trilho = trilho;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velocidade = velocidade;
        this.setBounds(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(cor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public void mover(double deltaT) {
        if (velocidade == 0) return;
        boolean sentidoHorario = velocidade > 0;
        double distancia = Math.abs(restante + velocidade * deltaT);
        int tLeft = trilho.getX();
        int tTop = trilho.getY();
        int tRight = tLeft + trilho.getWidth();
        int tBottom = tTop + trilho.getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) distancia; i++) {
            // Se deve ir à esquerda:
            if (x > tLeft && y == (sentidoHorario ? tBottom : tTop)) {
                x--;
            // Se deve ir à direita:
            } else if (x < tRight && y == (sentidoHorario ? tTop : tBottom)) {
                x++;
            // Se deve ir para cima:
            } else if (y > tTop && x == (sentidoHorario ? tLeft : tRight)) {
                y--;
            // Se deve ir para baixo:
            } else if (y < tBottom && x == (sentidoHorario ? tRight : tLeft)) {
                y++;
            // Se não for nenhum dos anteriores, o trem está descarrilhado. Coloca de novo no trilho.
            } else {
                x = tLeft;
                y = tTop;
            }
        }
        restante = distancia % 1;
        setLocation(x - 5, y - 5);
    }
}

public static class Jslider extends JPanel{

    private Jslider(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        JSlider control = new JSlider(0,100,25);
        control.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
        control.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        control.setPaintTicks(true);
        control.setFont(new Font("Serfi", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        control.setPaintLabels(true);
        control.setSnapToTicks(true);
        add(control);

    }
}

public class EventoSlider implements ChangeListener{


    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
         int fps = (int) source.getValue();
        System.out.println(fps);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Por que está tudo estático? Pode ser bobagem, mas tudo estar estático pode ser uma das fontes de seu problema.

Comment: veja se essa resposta lhe ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208128/28595

Comment: Esta pergunta é uma *follow-up* desta outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226377/132

Comment: Como assim estatico? @Articuno. Nao é necessariamente como o exemplo que mandou.

Comment: Help-me @VictorStafusa.

Comment: @CarlosDiego Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: @Articuno preciso implementar tbm deadlock entre os trens poderia me ajudar na logica? indenpendente da velocidade ambos nao podem colidir, um tem que esperar o outro passar para depois ele continuar caminho. O pro é fazer isso dinamicamente na medida que posso alterar a velocidade dos trens em tempo de execução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui, até que foi simples:

```
package trens;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class Trens {

    private static final double QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO = 20.0;

    public static void preparar() {
        JFrame t = new JFrame();
        t.setLayout(null);
        t.setSize(1200, 900);
        t.setTitle("Semáforo");
        t.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        t.setResizable(false);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Trilho t1 = new Trilho(300, 100, 300, 170);
        Trilho t2 = new Trilho(600, 100, 300, 170);
        Trilho t3 = new Trilho(450, 270, 300, 170);

        Trem a = new Trem(t1, Color.BLUE, 350, 100, 100.0);
        Trem b = new Trem(t2, Color.GREEN, 650, 100, 100.0);
        Trem c = new Trem(t3, Color.RED, 450, 335, 100.0);
        VelocityControl slider = new VelocityControl(a, 30, 150, 300, 170);
        VelocityControl slider2 = new VelocityControl(b, 900, 150, 300, 170);
        VelocityControl slider3 = new VelocityControl(c, 150, 330, 300, 170);
        t.add(a);
        t.add(b);
        t.add(c);
        t.add(t1);
        t.add(t2);
        t.add(t3);
        t.add(slider);
        t.add(slider2);
        t.add(slider3);
        Runnable moverTudo = () -> {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                a.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
                b.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
                c.mover(1 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO);
            });
        };
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(moverTudo, 0, (int) (1000 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Trens::preparar);
    }

    public static class Trilho extends JComponent {
        public Trilho(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }
    }

    public static class Trem extends JComponent {
        private Color cor;
        private Trilho trilho;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private double velocidade; // pixels por segundo
        private double restante; // Frações de pixels que faltou andar.

        public Trem(Trilho trilho, Color cor, int x, int y, double velocidade) {
            this.trilho = trilho;
            this.cor = cor;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.velocidade = velocidade;
            this.setBounds(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(cor);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        public void setVelocidade(double novaVelocidade) {
            this.velocidade = novaVelocidade;
        }

        public void mover(double deltaT) {
            if (velocidade == 0) return;
            boolean sentidoHorario = velocidade > 0;
            double distancia = Math.abs(restante + velocidade * deltaT);
            int tLeft = trilho.getX();
            int tTop = trilho.getY();
            int tRight = tLeft + trilho.getWidth();
            int tBottom = tTop + trilho.getHeight();

            for (int i = 0; i < (int) distancia; i++) {
                // Se deve ir à esquerda:
                if (x > tLeft && y == (sentidoHorario ? tBottom : tTop)) {
                    x--;
                // Se deve ir à direita:
                } else if (x < tRight && y == (sentidoHorario ? tTop : tBottom)) {
                    x++;
                // Se deve ir para cima:
                } else if (y > tTop && x == (sentidoHorario ? tLeft : tRight)) {
                    y--;
                // Se deve ir para baixo:
                } else if (y < tBottom && x == (sentidoHorario ? tRight : tLeft)) {
                    y++;
                // Se não for nenhum dos anteriores, o trem está descarrilhado. Coloca de novo no trilho.
                } else {
                    x = tLeft;
                    y = tTop;
                }
            }
            restante = distancia % 1;
            setLocation(x - 5, y - 5);
        }
    }

    public static class VelocityControl extends JPanel {
        private VelocityControl(Trem trem, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            JSlider control = new JSlider(0, 100, 25);
            control.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
            control.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
            control.setPaintTicks(true);
            control.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 12));
            control.setPaintLabels(true);
            control.setSnapToTicks(true);
            this.add(control);
            control.addChangeListener(e -> trem.setVelocidade(control.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

Mudei o nome da classe `Jslider` para `VelocityControl` para não confundir com a `JSlider` (note que uma tem o S maiúsculo e a outra minúsculo).

O truque para fazer o valor escolhido refletir na velocidade é o `control.addChangeListener(e -> trem.setVelocidade(control.getValue()));` com a sintaxe do lambda, isso fica bem simples e limpo.

Para ligar os trens aos controles, bastou passar o trem como um parâmetro   mais para o construtor do `VelocityControl`.

Um último detalhe é que você tinha usado `"Serfi"` ao invés de `"Serif"` no nome da fonte, um erro de digitação.

Comment: Perfeito @VictorStafusa, realmente tinha errado, ja tinha ate corrigido no meu codigo.

Comment: todos os trens estao rodando numa thread so?

Comment: @CarlosDiego Sim. O `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(moverTudo, 0, (int) (1000 / QUADROS_POR_SEGUNDO), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` cria apenas uma thread para ficar executando periodicamente o `moverTudo`. Entretanto, a execução de fato acontece dentro da EDT.

Comment: no caso preciso identificar uma provavel colisao entre os trens e fazer com que uma thread pause enquanto a outra do trem siga caminho, depois a thread pausada volta a percorrer.. isso para os 3 trens. Como esta implementado tem como fazer essa logica?

Comment: @CarlosDiego Tentar fazer isso com threads diferentes só vai te trazer dor de cabeça e nenhum benefício. A resposta é colocar alguma lógica dentro do `moverTudo` ou do método `mover` de cada trem que verifique se ocorreu uma colisão e decida o que fazer nesse caso.

Comment: Realmente, ai como poderia ser a verificaçao pra saber se eles podem colidir?

Comment: @CarlosDiego `Trem outro = ...; boolean colidiu = Math.abs(this.x - outro.x) < 10 && Math.abs(this.y - outro.y) < 10;` - No caso esses valores 10 ocorre porque essa é a largura e altura dos trens. Se a largura e altura puder variar, então você usaria `(this.width - outro.width) / 2` e `(this.height - outro.height) / 2`.

Comment: Na verdade, como o nome da classe já sugere, você vai precisar usar semáforos, literalmente rs. Quando o trem chegar no ponto onde as duas linhas coincidem, coloque um semáforo ali. Quando o trem chegar ali, verifique se está "SIGA", senão fique parado e aguarde o outro trem passar. Quando o trem passa e o sinal é "SIGA", move o trem e em seguida coloca "PARE" nesse sinal. Você precisa de 3 sinais, um para cada trecho de interseção entre as linhas de trem.

Comment: @Dudaskank voce tem algum exemplo que de pra aplicar de maneira facil e pratica de entender nesse projetinho?

Comment: Ótima resposta, eu tinha uma ideia de solução, mas de longe essa é uma forma bem menos trabalhosa e proporciona mais controle de tudo, parabens victor =)